# Flutter Permissions status NotAgain even on first launch

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, flutter-plugin

I'm using [permission](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission) plugin in order to check permissions status and request them if they are in `deny` state. But every time from first time the permission status for phone and storage are `notAgain`. Because of which I'm unable to request user to grant permission for `phone` and `storage`. I specified them in my android manifest file too.

here is code snippet to check and request permissions

```
List<Permissions> permissions = await Permission.getPermissionStatus([PermissionName.Location, PermissionName.Phone, PermissionName.Storage]);
    permissions.forEach((permission) {
      if(permission.permissionStatus.toString().contains('deny') ){
        neededPermissions.add(permission.permissionName);
      }
    });
if(neededPermissions.length > 0){
      requestPermissions(neededPermissions);
    }
```

I don't get the reason why they are `notAgain` from first time launch of app

Comment: Have you been able to fix this problem yet? I really need to in order to finish my app... its holding me back...

Comment: Right now, I'm using simple_permissions plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/simple_permissions) by making some changes in that plugin code. It's working good for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this answer hopefully someone will find it helpful.
In case someone is struggling with this. This package [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#-example-tab-)
offer great utilities to handle permissions correctly. It has recently been updated to include `isPermanentlyDenied` flag which is the same as "Don't Ask Again" on Android.

Comment: I have no idea why this would fix the problem... regardless, the fact that getPermissionStatus is outputting not again means the pop up won't appear... at least that's what It means on my end... but i would still very much like a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your calling request permission twice, Call request permission inside initState() for on launch request.

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

requestPermission();

  }

requestPermission() async {
final res = await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(
    Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
print("permission request result is " + res.toString());
```

}